# Ubuntu 12.04 launcher icons missing

Tags: 12.04, unity, icons

I just notice that the icons in the launcher are all missing. The launcher  is there, but it is empty. Now I have to use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to switch between opened applications. I don't know what happened. I am just opening a lot of chrome tabs. Can someone help me with it?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using intel graphics?  This may be an annoying bug that was only recently fixed in February in the precise-updates repository.  See:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mesa/+bug/1024768